# Where do I put my modules in an Elixir mix application?

Tags: elixir

I have a simple project that I have started call test. So I did:

```
mix new test
```

and I got the usual directory tree. In the lib directory, is test.ex. But I want test.ex to use a module called Mystuff, but I don't know where to put mystuff.ex because I get a compile error.

Here is test.ex (in the test/lib directory):

```
defmodule Test do

  use Mystuff

  @moduledoc """
  Documentation for Test.
  """

  @doc """
  Hello world.

  ## Examples

      iex> Test.hello
      :world

  """
  def hello do
    Mystuff.bye()
  end
end
```

and here is mystuff.ex which I have also included in test/lib:

```
defmodule Test.Mystuff do
  def bye do
    IO.puts "bye"
  end
end
```

however if I run "iex -S mix" from the project's home directory (test) I get:

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Compiling 3 files (.ex)

== Compilation error on file lib/test/mystuff.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/test/mystuff.ex:1: cannot define module Test.Mystuff because it is currently being defined in lib/mystuff.ex:1
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

So am I naming something wrong? Using something wrong? Putting something in the wrong directory?

Comment: Your are defining the `Test.MyStuff` module twice. Once in `lib/test/mystuff.ex` and the other in `lib/mystuff.ex`. Change one of their names and it should compile.

Comment: After you remove the duplicate module, you are also going to want to learn the difference between [`import`, `alias`, `use` and `require`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html)

Comment: _Sidenote:_ tests are to have `.exs` extension to prevent their auto-compilation. `ExUnit` tests make no sense without `ExUnit` itself and `doctest` macro.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `use Mystuff` with `alias Test.Mystuff`.